# NFC alert not always dismissed after reading data

Tags: swift, swiftui, nfc

**Context** 
I am developing a numeric boardgame (with mobile application). Players can interact with application by scanning their badge (which contains UUID).

**My problem**
I have created a NFCReader service to read data from NFC badge. When I call `scan()` method from this service, NFC popup is displayed as well and it dismissed as expected when I put NFC bagde on my phone. But when I reiterate this operation with the NFC badge **already scotched on my phone** before trigger NFC detection, NFC popup is displayed as expected but **sometimes**, it is not dismissed after reading data.

**Expected situation** : 
[image]

**Bug situation** (when my badge is already scotched on my phone before scan method called:
[image]

**NFCReader Service**

```
class NFCReader: NSObject, NFCNDEFReaderSessionDelegate, ObservableObject {

    static var instance = NFCReader()
    var session: NFCNDEFReaderSession?
    
    var onRecordCallBack: ((_ badgeId: String) -> Void)?

    func scan(message: String, onRecord: @escaping (_ badgeId: String) -> Void) {
        guard NFCReaderSession.readingAvailable else {
            return
        }
        
        self.onRecordCallBack = onRecord

        self.session = NFCNDEFReaderSession(delegate: self, queue: .main, invalidateAfterFirstRead: false)
        self.session?.alertMessage = message
        self.session?.begin()
    }
    
    func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didInvalidateWithError error: Error) {
        if let readerError = error as? NFCReaderError {
            print("Error NFC reader : \(readerError.localizedDescription)")
        }
        self.session = nil
    }

    func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didDetectNDEFs messages: [NFCNDEFMessage]) {
        
        guard
            let message = messages.first,
            let record = message.records.first,
            let badgeId = String(data: record.payload, encoding: .utf8) else {
            return
        }

        if let onRecordCallBack = self.onRecordCallBack {
            onRecordCallBack(badgeId)
        }
        
        self.session?.invalidate()
    }
}
```

**ViewModel** when NFCReader is used

```
struct InGameTravelView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = InGameTravelViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if viewModel.isScanning {
                Text("Scan your badge")
                    .onAppear() {
                        self.viewModel.scan()
                    }.onTapGesture {
                        self.viewModel.scan()
                    }
                ForEach(viewModel.pilots) { pilot in
                    Text("\(pilot.player.name) \(pilot.player.role.name)")
                        .onTapGesture {
                            viewModel.currentPilot = pilot
                            viewModel.isScanning = false
                        }
                }
            } else {
                switch viewModel.currentPilot.player.role.slug {
                case .GOOD :
                    GoodPilotActionView(pilot: $viewModel.currentPilot) { selectedMatePilot in
                        viewModel.onActionFinished(selectedMatePilot)
                    }
                case .BAD :
                    BadPilotActionView(pilot: $viewModel.currentPilot) {
                        //
                    }
                }
            }
        }.onAppear() {
            viewModel.fetchData()
        }
    }
}

extension InGameTravelView {
    class InGameTravelViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var pilots: [Pilot] = []
        @Published var pilotsAlreadyPlayed: [Pilot] = []
        @Published var isScanning = true
        @Published var currentPilot = Pilot.fake()
        
        func fetchData() {
            /* Retrieve current round */
            let round = GameManager.instance.state.currentRound
            /* Retrieve pilots */
            self.pilots = round.pilots
            
            if let pilot = self.pilots.first {
                self.currentPilot = pilot
            }
        }
        
        func scan() {
            NFCReader.instance.scan(message: "Scan your badge") { badgeId in
                print("badgeId : \(badgeId)")
                let round = GameManager.instance.state.currentRound
                guard let pilot = round.getPilotByBadgeId(badgeId: badgeId) else {
                    return
                }
                self.currentPilot = pilot
                self.isScanning = false
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I manually invalidate NFC session (`self.session?.invalidate()`) to hide popup as quickly as possible (to avoid players doing it by themself).

I would like to insist on the fact that the bug is **happening randomly**. Sometime, it works as expected (GIF 1) even if the badge is scotched before trigger scan.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check whether there are some error responses occurred, but they do not be caught. So does they some related logs be found in the termind.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32068381)